# Rails controllers naming syntax: When to pluralize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If i am generating a controller, should I make the controller name plural?

For example, I am generating a "central" controller to be the root directory (index) of the site. Is it fine to do "rails g controller central"?

I am getting mixed messages from visiting various websites.

It doesn't make that much sense to pluralize it, but I don't want to mess with Rails internal functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it should always be plural. It's convenient to pluralize only when the controller is associated with a model.

The [rails generate guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) itself gives an example of a `CreditCard` controller that is not pluralized. I don't think the rails ***guides*** would give a wrong example.

Answer (score 1):

`rails g controller central` will give you `CentralController`.

The "mixed messages" comes from less-than-perfect domain analysis, where each controller controls one list of model objects. `class PostsController` presents a list of `class Post`, objects, for example. Often the better analyses introduces a DIFFERENT name into the system. Such as a `class BlogController` that controls a list of `class 
Post` model objects.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the convention is to pluralize the controller name, and the corresponding model is singular.

Comment: that's what I ... raled against. In MVC-land, a controller should generally _not_ have a "corresponding model". Otherwise (disregarding the actual Rails plumbing), you really just have one domain-concept split in two.